# Lazy evaluation in a Map

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a function that executes other functions (which return `Strings`) depending on an input.
For example:

```
def execute(input: String) = {
    val actions = Map("foo" -> someObject.doStuff(), "bar" -> someObject.doThing())
    actions.get(input) }
```

Is there a way to make the functions in the `Map` to be called only if the corresponding key exists?

Comment: what is the default function you want to call if key is doesn't exist?

Comment: Then None should be returned.

Comment: You can start with something like: `if (actions isDefinedAt input) actions.get(input) else None`. Better yet, try to use `scala.util.Try`!

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to convert the values to a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk#Functional_programming).

Comment: @jrook `Map#get` already returns an `Option[T]` -- no need to check `isDefinedAt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
object someObject {
  def doStuff() = "foo"
  def doThing() = "bar"

}

//if you need a string as a return value.
//there will be empty string for missing keys
def execute(input: String):String = {
  val actions = Map( "foo" -> someObject.doStuff _ ,
                     "bar" -> someObject.doThing _ )

  actions.getOrElse(input,()=>"")()
}


//if you need an Option[String] as a return value.
//there will be None value for missing keys
def executeOption(input: String):Option[String] = {
  val actions = Map( "foo" -> someObject.doStuff _ ,
                     "bar" -> someObject.doThing _ )

  actions.get(input).map(_())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your executeOption was exactly what I was looking for. I was also wondering how to implement this when some of the functions in someObject take parameters?

Comment: this is quite complicated using pure scala. the problem is that in scala we can transform method into function literal using eta notation like `someObject.doStuff _ `, but function literals with parameters are not supported out of the box. There is a FunctionN type class in cats library that allows doing something like that using macros, but I'm not a very good at this staff.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you are not really looking for `lazy map`. You are trying to build some kind of execution engine, which does something based on string input.

Now, the simple trick to achieve this is to have a actual `functions` in your `Map` and execute the corresponding function for the input string.

So, lets say you have an object A,

```
object A {
  var i = 1

  def doFirstThing(): Unit = {
    i = i + 1
    println(s"first thing :: $i")
  }

  def doSecondThing(): Unit = {
    i = i - 1
    println(s"second thing :: $i")
  }
}
```

And you want to build an executor for executing `doFirstThing` for input `"first"` and `doSecondThing` for input `"second"`.

So, now you need to create `functions` `f1` and `f2` which will execute `A.doFirstThing()` and `A.doSecondThing()`.

Its pretty simple actually,

```
scala> val f1 = () => A.doFirstThing()
// f1: () => Unit = $$Lambda$1235/1187572055@7e192338

scala> val f2 = () => A.doSecondThing()
// f2: () => Unit = $$Lambda$1236/1696761182@47df3efe
```

Or, you can use `_` to convert `def` (`methods`) to functions,

```
scala> val f1 = A.doFirstThing _
// f1: () => Unit = $$Lambda$1317/1501701470@7306836f

scala> val f2 = A.doSecondThing _
// f2: () => Unit = $$Lambda$1318/545144829@2a3251ad
```

Now, you can define your map using these,

```
scala> def execute(input: String): Unit = {
     |   val map = Map(
     |     "first" -> f1,
     |     "second" -> f2
     |   )
     | 
     |   map.get(input).foreach(f => f())
     | }
// execute: (input: String)Unit

scala> execute("first")
// first thing :: 2

scala> execute("second")
// second thing :: 1

scala> execute("second")
// second thing :: 0

scala> execute("first")
// first thing :: 1

scala> execute("first")
// first thing :: 2
```

And it will plainly ignore all other inputs,

```
scala> execute("abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way how to execute object methods inside a `Map`. But you first have to put functions into the map. What you did, was putting results of object methods into your map. So your methods were executed and their results were put as values into the map.

Let's assume, that your methods are defined in this class:

```
class SomeObject {
  def doStuff(): String = "I did stuff"
  def doThing(): String = "I did a thing"
}
```

And you have an instance of the class:

```
val someObject = new SomeObject
```

First way, how to delay execution of these methods is to create new function using lambdas and execute methods inside these lambdas:

```
val actions = Map(
  "foo" -> (() => someObject.doStuff()),
  "bar" -> (() => someObject.doThing()),
)
```

You can use special syntax to convert object methods directly into lambdas:

```
val actions = Map(
  "foo" -> someObject.doStuff _,
  "bar" -> someObject.doThing _
)
```

If you specify type of the map explicitly, than you can get rid of the underscore too:

```
val actions: Map[String, () => String] = Map(
  "foo" -> someObject.doStuff,
  "bar" -> someObject.doThing
)
```

Next, you need to get the function from the map. If there is no function for the key, than use a default function - one, that always returns `None`

```
val action = actions.getOrElse(input, () => None)
```

And finally, you invoke the action:

```
action()
```

Comment: Please note, that the final `action` returns either a `String` or `None`. They do not share a reasonable common parent class. Return value of the `action ` can therefore be `java.lang.Object` / `scala.AnyRef`, or `java.io.Serializable`, none of those are too useful.